# Why isn't lo-menubar installed by default in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

Will I face any problems by installing the lo-menubar to give libreoffice global menus in Natty?

I'm wondering why it isn't installed by default. Are there stability problems or anything?

Answer (score 10):

From what I've read, there may be cases where it does not work correctly. For now, at least, it is not enabled by default:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/lo-menubar/+bug/760879
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lo-menubar/+bug/739184

Answer (score 5):

There are still a few rough edges to be worked out in lo-menubar, so until then it will not be installed/enabled by default.

For example, on rare occasions the window opens with the menu inside of it, and then the menu disappears (after a few seconds) and shows up in the unity panel as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are still rough edges (as of today and Ubuntu 11.10, version 0.1), especially *crashes* that only occur when the extension is installed.

As a consequence, you should definitely *not* install it now.