# Why doesn't LibreOffice work with the HUD?

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu, hud

So I have tried out a couple daily builds and beta 1, and love HUD. However, currently LibreOffice does not play nice with HUD and I was wondering if there was a way to make it work with HUD. Kinda like the lo-menubar that applies the menu bar to the global menu, if there was means to get LibreOffice to work with HUD. Or might this question be too soon for an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you install [lo-menubar](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lo-menubar) [image: Install lo-menubar], then the HUD  works with LibreOffice. It's the same mechanism.

It hasn't been used by default because it hasn't been stable enough. But whether or not it will be default by the time 12.04 is released, I don't know.

- [Why isn't lo-menubar installed by default in LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37726/why-isnt-lo-menubar-installed-by-default-in-libreoffice)

Comment: Is this answer still relevant in 13.04? AFAIK, lo-menubar is not available anymore, and LO integration with the HUD is still very bad.

Comment: I don't know what "bad" means. We have libreoffice-gtk and at least in 13.10, it's installed by default and seems to be working nicely.

Comment: Funny, doesn't work here at all, only for very basic commands like Open and Quit. I though this was with everybody, since I've seen other complaints about it on the net. Good to know it's working for you (and probably more people), anyway. :)