# Head Up Display (HUD)

Tags: unity, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't LibreOffice work with the HUD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115412/why-doesnt-libreoffice-work-with-the-hud)

I cannot see many application (such as LibreOffice) compatible with HUD . Is the HUD feature fully functional in 12.04 LTS?

If not when the amazing HUD feature of Ubuntu will become as a fully functional production ready state?